# Exception thrown: RubyGem version error: activerecord(2.3.8 not >= 3.0.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I keep getting this error and I am stumped. So the application is in rails 2.3.8 and here is my gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

aaronh-chronic (0.3.9)
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
activerecord (2.3.8)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
arel (2.0.8)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.10)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
erubis (2.6.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
file-tail (1.0.5)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.15)
mime-types (1.16)
passenger (3.0.2)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.1.0)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (2.3.8)
railties (3.0.4)
rake (0.8.7)
riddle (1.2.2)
rubygems-update (1.5.2)
spruz (0.2.5)
thinking-sphinx (2.0.2)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.24)
whenever (0.6.2)
```

I had rubygems 1.3.7 and i downgraded to 1.3.5 and the error persists...

gem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

What can i do to resolve

Comment: Is there a reason You can't use rubygems latest 1.5.2? I have plenty of rails 2.x apps running 1.5.2. I don't think RubyGems is your problem, Looks like one of your app gems wants to use rails 3 activerecord

Answer (score 0):

Could be you "Remote source", try doing:

```
gem sources -r http://gems.rubyonrails.org
```

then add:

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

Also... you can post which gems do you request in your `environment.rb` file (RoR 2.X) or `Gemfile` (RoR 3.X)

Answer (score 0):

just edit the rails version in the `config/environment.rb` file to 2.3.8